# Why not take the creature to the nearest beach?

Tags: plot-device, the-shape-of-water

In the Shape of Water, Eliza waits several days for the "rainy season" and for the nearby canal to fill with rain water so they can release the creature.

But not only do the have a car already (the “laundry van”), but we're told that the city is

> "*near the coast, but far from everything else*"

---

**Why do they need to wait for the canal to fill when they can just head to the nearest beach in order to free the creature?**

Comment: I don't think the spoiler tags are needed here. You've not given away the ending and the fact that he gets "rescued" is revealed extensively in the trailer and marketing.

Comment: Maybe it can't handle salt water?

Comment: IIRC it needs ca. 5-10% of salt in the water - which is probably less than sea water.

Comment: @MartinSchröder The creature certainly doesn't live in freshwater, so unless it lives on the knife edge of some very particular interface zone between a river and the ocean, it must live in plain old seawater (which is about 3.5% salt, by the way).

Comment: If it can't handle seawater, it's gonna have a really hard time getting back to South America (assuming that's the plan).

Answer (score -3):

There are inland cities that have rivers but no beaches (e.g., Sacramento), in which case they could swim to the sea. But that raises the problem that the creature needs salt water.

Perhaps there were no *accessible* beaches nearby (due to cliffs, private property, etc.) and they didn't think the creature could survive long enough to reach one of them.

Comment: The film is set in Baltimore which doesn’t lack for shoreline access....

Comment: Baltimore doesn't really have a *beach* per se (with sand, sunburned tourists, etc.), but it is a port city on the Chesapeake Bay with access to the ocean. Just ask Francis Scott Key.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was set in Baltimore. In that case, this may be just a plot hole, like the fact that they waited for the water level to rise and fill the lock, rather than just going to a dock directly on the bay.

Comment: @S.Dennett Ironically there were so many plot holes that you could't use that script to hold water.  On the other hand I personally loved the movie.